# jquery append and remove dynamic table row errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have an issue with my jquery code. It is designed to append new table row when the `ajouter` button is clicked.

It works well except that it adds rows depending on the number of rows already present. If there are five rows on the table and you click the add button it will add five empty rows instead of one and I don't know where the error is coming from.

This is the code:

```
<?php

echo '<td>'
    . '<input type="button" class="deleteButton" value="Supp."/> '
    . '<a href="javascript:void(0);" >'
    . '<input type="button" class="addCF" value="Ajouter"/>'
    . '</a>'
    . '</td>';

echo'</tr>';
?>                          
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".addCF").click(function () {
        $("#demoajax").append('<tr><td><input type="text"  name="brice2[]" value="" placeholder="Ref" /> </td><td><input type="text"   name="brice[]" value="" placeholder="Label" /></td><td><input type="text" name="mytext[]" value="" placeholder="Quantite en besoin" /></td><td><input type="text" name="brice51[]" value="" placeholder="Unite" /></td><td><input type="text" name="brice52[]" value="" placeholder="Fabrication Utile" /></td><td> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remCF"><input type="button"   value="Supp"/></a></td></tr>');
    });
    $("#demoajax").on('click', '.remCF', function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the error and what is happening currently?

Comment: Where is you `#demoajax` container? Please show us entire code to understand the problem properly.

Comment: The code you shared (when the table and an opening tr is added) works - it adds 1 row per click.